# Real integral by complex methods.

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, contour-integration, complex-integration

I wish to compute the integral $\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2}\text{cos}(x^2)\mathrm dx$ using complex integration techniques. I'm integrating the function $e^{-z^2}$ over the boundary of the circular sector $\{z:|z|<a, 0\leq \arg z \leq \pi/8\}$. I'm having difficulty integrating the said function over the arc, i.e. the second piece of the contour. I used the parametrization $\gamma_2(t)=ae^{it}, 0\leq t \leq \pi/8$. I think it reduces to bounding $|e^{-a^2e^{2it}}|$ but I can't seem to bound this. Any help is appreciated.

I've already looked at this:[Integral of $e^{-x^2}\cos(x^2)$ using residues](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/455882/integral-of-e-x2-cosx2-using-residues), but wish to proceed without considering the real parts.

Comment: Regarding your needed bound:  in general we have $|e^z| = e^{\text{Re}(z)}$, which should help give you a bound...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the famous Euler Integral formula related to the $\Gamma$-function. The derivation is pretty straight forward and can be completed by advanced high school students.

It states

$$\int_0^{\infty}u^{ns-1}\exp(-au^n)\cos(bu^n)du=\dfrac{\Gamma(s)}{n|p|^s}\cos (\alpha s),$$

in which $p=a+bi \implies |p|=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ and $\tan \alpha = \dfrac{b}{a}$.

Comment: I was able to solve the problem but did not use the above answer. I'm accepting it so that the problem is no longer unanswered.

Comment: Hmm ... you should not accept the answer if it didn't answer your question :). Rather post your method as an answer.